# how to upgrade css-loader from v0.28 to v1.0.0?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, postcss-loader

In css-loader v0.28, I used root option ,but In css-loader v1.0.0,the option was removed,I checked the changelog(https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and Found this:

> remove root option, use postcss-loader with postcss-url plugin

but I could not integrate postcss-url very well.

for example,my previous css-loader option was:

```
{
   loader: 'css-loader',
   options: {
       root: 'static',
       minimize: true
   }
}
```

So when I wrote some css snippet like that :

```
background-image: url("/mobile/img/logo-new.png");
```

after css-loader parsed,it would changed to:

```
background-image: url("/static/mobile/img/logo-new.png");
```

I like previous style but maybe we should upgrade css-loader,so should use [postcss-url](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url).I could not use it very well,the docs also could not give me more info,so I came here and hope someone could help me.

what postcss-url option should I use to get the correct answer?